# GT Base, GT Purchase not equal amount

Tags: magento-1.9

I have hundreds of orders in online shopping built with Magento 1.9. I found out that one order has GT Base and GT Purchase does not match. I have no idea how to did it happened and how to prevent them from happening in the future.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

GT Base - The Grand total in Base Currency

GT Purchased - The Grand total in the currency with which the order was placed.

For example: the buyer might have placed order using GBP, however the base currency of the site might be in USD. In this case, GT Base will be in USD and GT Purchased will be in GBP.